# I am attempting to create a textbox for a website that can change the text to whatever format the user wishes

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a textbox for a website that can change the text to whatever format the user wishes. However, this is not working. This is my code so far.

```
<body>

  <h1><b><u> A Simple   Word Processor  </u></b></h1>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("edit").style.fontstyle = "italic";
    }
    </script>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()"> Italics </button>
    <br> <br>
    <textarea id="edit" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please define "not working". What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: So, you're trying to make a WYSIWYG HTML editor?  Why not use one of the many already out there, such as TinyMCE?

Comment: TinyMCE is nice, but I really like how customisable this one is: http://wysihtml.com

Comment: I can only upvote brad's comment once. But I would upvote it about a billion times if I could. Do not waste your life reinventing this useless wheel. The WYSIWYG has been done way better and with way more support than it will ever need and it is still a raging piece of s***. Even the highest reputations in WYSIWYG development still get trampled with rampant bugs and horrible interpretation of the neverending stupidity of their users trying to shovel pasted crap from MS Word and every other garbage editor out there into a field and hope by way of black magic it just works perfectly. Back out!

Answer (score 0):

Like everybody says, **don't reinvent the wheel** and pick something like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) or my favourite [WysiHTML](http://wysihtml.com/).

However, your error is that Javascript uses *camelcased* CSS properties, so...

```
document.getElementById("edit").style.fontstyle = "italic";
```

should be changed to

```
document.getElementById("edit").style.fontStyle = "italic";
```